# Implementing reflection in x86 assembly (editing the program whilst running)

Tags: assembly

I'd like to write an assembly program which once loaded into memory, writes new instructions over itself, but I'm not 100% certain how to proceed as I have some doubts about the instruction pointer and other assembly concepts. My hypothesised approach:

```
_func:

    push rip    ; Not allowed to push RIP, how can I read from RIP?
    jmp stage1

    stage2:

    mov eax, 0
    ret

    stage1:

    pop rbx

    ; How many times should I increment rbx to point to ‘mov eax, 0’?
    ; Assuming this is done:

    ;Move opcodes for ‘mov eax, 1’ into memory where ‘mov eax, 0’ located

    mov [rbx], 0xB8
    mov [rbx+1], 0x01
    mov [rbx+2], 0x00
    mov [rbx+3], 0x00
    mov [rbx+4], 0x00

    jmp stage2
```

When it jumps to stage 2, instead of 'mov eax, 0', it will encounter the opcodes 'B8 01 00 00 00' and interpret 'mov eax, 1.' Is my general approach correct, and can someone fill in that gap in the code?

---

**Additional Confusion/Issue**

Does RBX point to the first byte of the line of instructions, or the 'whole' line? Is the aforementioned approach correct, or should I have written:

```
mov [rbx], B801000000h
```

---

**Operating System:** Mac OS X 10.9        **Assembler:** NASM

Comment: I wouldn't call this "reflection" - that term is for somewhat higher level concept. Self-modifying code is more like it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676966/implementing-reflection-in-x86-assembly-editing-the-program-whilst-running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 16-bit "real mode" doing this is simple. When I began assembler programming I implemented a loop using reflection.

However under 16- or 32-bit "protected mode" or under "long mode" (64-bit) this is more tricky:

In these modes memory can be protected against overwriting. Since the "Pentium Pro" processor it is also possible to protect memory against execution.

Both Windows and Linux use these features so by default memory that can be modified cannot contain executable code and memory containing executable code cannot be overwritten.

You have to allocate memory that is both writeable and executable (or to change the memory access of existing memory). See "VirtualAlloc" and "VirtualProtect" functions in Windows or "mmap" and "mprotect" in Linux. Then you have to move the code into that piece of memory.

By the way: The following command is wrong:

```
jmp stage1
```

It must be "call" instead of "jmp" because "jmp" does not "push" the return address on the stack.

Comment: On Mac OS X, what's the equivalent of the VirtualAlloc etc. functions?

Comment: As far as I know Mac OS X is similar to Linux so it should (I'm not sure!) also be "mmap". However I know that iOS does not allow memory that is both writeable and executable. Maybe Mac OS X does not allow either. In this case reflection would not be possible.

Comment: Can I circumvent using mmap if I run the code at kernel privilege level, i.e. ring 0?

Comment: On kernel level you require different functions than mmap or VirtualAlloc. Unfortunately I do not know much about kernel programming in these three operating systems so I do not know which functions to use there. However in ring 0 the memory pages also have access flags so you cannot write to write-protected memory and you cannot execute code in execution-protected memory.

Comment: Supposing, hypothetically, there were no memory restrictions, was my code to move the opcodes correct? (Ignoring the rest of the code, i.e. loading rip, etc. Just the last lines.)

Comment: It looks quite good. However you have to ensure that the "mov eax,0" instruction that you overwrite is 5 bytes long. As far as I know "mov eax,0" can be coded using 4, 5 or 6 bytes.

Comment: Indeed. I think I'll build an executable, disassemble it, and check all the opcodes.

Comment: Just a note: I don't think the jump command is 'wrong.' I didn't intend to push a return address by doing that. Had push RIP worked, the pop after the first stage label was to load that into RBX. Anyway, I found the best way of reading the instruction pointer is by using either (MASM) 'lea rax, [rip]' or (NASM) 'lea rax, [rel $].'

Comment: Thank you for the referral to VirtualProtect(), it worked. Also found some interesting uses of it for anti-debugging, such as to strip an application's PE header during runtime. In addition, I've seen it used for more malicious purposes since statically analysing some malware.

Answer (score 1):

In 16-bit "real mode":

```
mov bx, stage2      ; NASM get offset address

mov cs:[bx], 0xB8
mov cs:[bx+1], 0x01
mov cs:[bx+2], 0x00
mov cs:[bx+3], 0x00
mov cs:[bx+4], 0x00
```